# Set of functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb Z_p$ is a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider $A = \{f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\}$ the set of maps from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Define $B=\{H_F:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p\}$, with $H_F(x) = \overline{f(x)}$.

If we consider the usual operations:
$$(H_F+H_G)(x)=H_F(x)+H_G(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad (H_F.H_G)(x) = H_F(x).H_G(x)$$

Is $B$ a ring? Is $B$ a field?

My doubt is if $B$ would have only one neutral element for $+$. Because if I consider $q:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $q(x)=px$ and $r:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $r(x)=0$, then $H_Q$ and $H_R$ would both work as neutral elements for $+$, or am I wrong? A ring should have only one neutral element for $+$, right?

Thanks.

Comment: $H_Q$ and $H_R$ are both the same map.

Comment: $r$ and $q$ are elements of $A$, not elements of $B$. And as elements of $A$, clearly $q$ is not a neutral element.